# MRTK Gaze Provider Pointer disappears with Oculus Rift and Touch

Tags: oculus, mrtk

When using an Oculus Rift, if the Touch controllers are disabled (turned off), there is a pointer attached to the HMD and I can use the Gaze Provider, but when at least one of the controllers is enabled, the pointer associated with the Gaze Provider disappears.

Is this the intended behaviour?
Is there a way to re-enable the Gaze Provider pointer?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like the currently intended behavior, but I'd like to better understand your use case to try to support it better.

Do your controllers gain their own pointing ray when connected? If not (and your pointers profile contains a DefaultControllerPointer prefab)

[image: DefaultControllerPointer]

then we might have some misconfigurations with regards to the Touch controllers.

Otherwise, if you never want controller-specific pointers and only want to use the gaze pointer, you can select and delete the DefaultControllerPointer definition, or uncheck Oculus Touch from the Controller Type dropdown.

[image]

Comment: Yes, when I connect the controllers, each one gets its own pointer with associated pointing ray shown, while the HMD's one disappears.

Comment: Great, thanks for the additional info!
Yeah, removing the DefaultControllerPointer definition from that profile or unchecking Oculus Touch from the Controller Type dropdown should allow you to continue using the gaze ray with controllers.
For full functionality, you may want to add Oculus Touch to the Controller Type dropdown for the GGVPointer prefab in the same profile.

Comment: Unchecking Oculus Touch from the DefaultControllerPointer's Controller Type dropdown and checking Oculus Touch in the GGVPointer's Controller Type dropdown seems to work fine, although I lose the pointers from the controllers. Thank you very much for the help, Kurtis!